# How to run Rails delayed_job with Passenger in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, delayed-job

I've a Rails 4.1.x app with `delayed_job` gem. To run the jobs I need to issue

```
rake jobs:work
```

My hosting works with `passenger`. **How can I run my jobs in a way that they are started just after the app?**.

I've been reading and it looks like a complicated thing, because I need a single process running those jobs. So far I've been using `screen`, but I'm looking for a ruby way to solve this. There is a lot of documentation on `development`, but `production` seems to be forgotten.

Comment: Are you not able to use cron? The way you phrased your question it sounds like you might not have shell access to your server, so I'm wondering what limitations you're working with.

Comment: I have shell access, that why I'm using `screen`. But I'm looking for a `delayed_job`/`passenger` configuration that works in all cases, because right now, if the server reboots, I loose that screen process, and I need to ssh and bootstrap another one manually (puaj).